# ircd-hybdrid, SSL, and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: ssl, irc

I have a small server running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. On it I wanted to set up IRC with SSL support. it appears that ircd-hybrid is most popular. I am not married to using it so other options are welcome. However, I am not seeing other options.

Anyway, I following the instructions (I listed a couple at the end) and install ircd-hybrid no problem. It's actually running now. However, I noticed that SSL isn't working. The port is never being listened to. Digging deeper, I look back at the building process and notice that OpenSSL isn't being included.

So I have been trying to build and just to clarify, here is the ./configure output:

```
Compiling ircd-hybrid 7.2.2

Installing into: /usr
Ziplinks ................ yes
**OpenSSL ................. no**
Modules ................. shared
IPv6 support ............ yes
Net I/O implementation .. sigio
EFnet server ............ no (use example.conf)
Halfops support ......... yes
Small network ........... no
G-Line voting ........... yes[/CODE]
```

A few line up in the output of the ./configure script I notice that it seems that all the encryption algos are unavailable!

```
checking for OpenSSL... /usr
checking for OpenSSL 0.9.6 or above... found
checking for RSA_free in -lcrypto... yes
checking for EVP_bf_cfb... no
checking for EVP_cast5_cfb... no
checking for EVP_idea_cfb... no
checking for EVP_rc5_32_12_16_cfb... no
checking for EVP_des_ede3_cfb... no
checking for EVP_des_cfb... no
```

Which if you look into the configure script you'll see that at least one of the encryption libraries need to be enabled. This is a hunch as I am not entirely positive about this. It seems that OpenSSL has disabled RC5 and a couple other algos.

I've rebuilt and installed OpenSSL with the enable-rc5 and other flags but no dice.

This is on Ubuntu 12.04. Help? Anyone? I'd like to enable SSL on IRC on my personal server. It doesn't have to be ircd-hybrid.

I have been looking at the forums on [Ubuntu](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12435171#post12435171) and generally following these [instructions](https://marvelserv.com/setting-up-ircd-hybrid-and-hybserv-services-with-ssl-on-ubuntu/).

Thanks!

Comment: The instructions you linked to worked for me: https://marvelserv.com/setting-up-ircd-hybrid-and-hybserv-services-with-ssl-on-ubuntu/